# Solving for constants of integration continuously resulting in trivial statement 0=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, fluid-dynamics

I am attempting to solve a fairly simply pair of ODEs that represent a flow field for a fluid dynamics problem. I am attempting to find the particle path but I am getting stuck trying to find x and y first. The ODEs are:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = U $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = Usin(x-Ut) $$

... where U is any arbitrary constant.

However, I am continually running into this situation where my constant of integration ends up equaling an expression that, when plugged in, results in 0=0. This is a true statement but it does not allow me to approach the actual equations I'm looking for. For example, the result I get from solving our first equation:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = U $$
$$ dx = U \cdot dt$$
$$ \int dx = \int U \cdot dt$$
$$ x = Ut+c$$

Where we are negating the constant on the LHS because subtracting it still results in a constant on the RHS. So, solving for our constant c I then get:

$$ x = Ut + c \implies c = x-Ut$$

But when plugging that in we get:

$$ x = Ut + x-Ut$$
$$x-x = Ut-Ut$$
$$0 = 0$$

The initial conditions given are:

$$(x_0, y_0); t = t_0$$

I'm a bit lost here. What part of the equation am I looking for my final x and y, which I can then use to find the path? Plugging in the initial conditions at any point still results in 0 = 0, so I suspect this is where I am going wrong. The same thing happens when I do this with the second equation. I feel as though I am missing an extremely simple thing, but I am a bit fuzzy on the solving.

Comment: The constant isn't determined by the differential equation, but by an initial condition that is separately given/made, in this case you need to plug it into $x(t_0)=x_0$ to get $c$.

Comment: Are you missing an equation for $y$?

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you for pointing out the typo. The second equation was dy/dt. I have fixed it. I realize now that I am having trouble wrapping my head around why we don't plug in the ICs to every available x, y, and t - which is why everytime I do this, I get the trivial expression. It strikes me as odd that there is an expression that mixes both x and x_0, y and y_0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since the additive constant $c$ vanishes on derivation, every function of the form $x(t) = Ut + c$ solves your differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = U$. So in order to determine $c$, you would need an aditional bit of constraint or information. For example, an initial value $x(t_0)$ will do.

Substituting an equation into itself unsurprisingly gives you $0 = 0$ and that has nothing to do with calculus. From any equation $y = z$, you can subtract $y$ from the left side and $z$ from the right side (as they're equal) and get $0 = 0$. This is equivalent to what you did.